# Choose record type based on picklist value

Tags: custom-button, record-type

I have a custom object `Cov__c` and I have a picklist on that object `Risks_c`.

I have another custom object `Address__c`, which is a child of `Cov__c`. I have two record types for `Address__c` because I need to display different fields on the page layout, based on the value that's selected in the `Risks__c` picklist.

The record types are called `Auth_Risk` and `Terr_Risk`.

So, when the user selects `Auth` in the `Risks__c` picklist, and then adds addresses to the contract, then I need to show the `Auth_Risk` record type. For any other value in the picklist, I need to show the `Terr_Risk` record type.

I have created a list button and added this code:

```
`{!IF( ISPICKVAL(Cov__c.Risk__c,'Terr'), '/a0Z/e?ent=01I180000004KaV&RecordType=012180000008Tw5, '/a0Z/e?ent=01I180000004KaV&RecordType=012180000008Tw0')}`
```

When I try to save, it just says error. I am not sure what is wrong. Can anyone help please?

Comment: and have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Hi, yes, I have tried creating a new List Button, but I cannot find out how to specify the record type in the link. This is the code I am using for the List Button: `{!IF(ISPICKVAL(Cov__c.Risk__c,'Terr'),  '/a0Z/e' , 'a0Z/e')}`

Comment: Hello @crop1645 - I have amended my code once again. Are you able to help me see why this is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment try getting the button to work on a single record type first then add in the if statement. An example of the result should look something like below:

```
/006/e?retURL={!Cov__c.Id}&CustomFieldIDFromChildRecord={!Cov__c.Id}&RecordType={!IF(ISPICKVAL(Cov__c.Risk__c,'Terr'), "012180000008Tw5","012180000008Tw0")}&ent=Opportunity
```

since the only thing in the URL that is conditional is the Record Type Id, you can just use the IF statement for the RecordType parameter.

Comment: Can I use that syntax in a list button?

Comment: @Lily Sorry, I should refrain from answering on my phone app, didn't read the url correctly ent= 01I180000004KaV should be fine, I thought that was the retURL parameter you were setting. The easiest thing to do is create a new record with the standard new button then copy the url and wherever it has the parent record id swap it out with the merge field. Once you have it working for a single record type then add the if statement and swap out the record id where needed. I'll update my answer with how it should probably end up looking.

Comment: Thanks @Jenny B, Do you know how I can actually make the link work on the button?

Comment: @Lily I added an example of what the URL should look like in the end.

Comment: I have changed my code for the button now. `/006/e?retURL={!Cov__c.Id}&CustomFieldIDFromChildRecord={!Cov__c.Id}&RecordType={!IF(ISPICKVAL(Cov__c.Risk__c,'Terr'), "012180000008Tw0","012180000008Tw5")}&ent=Address__c` and when I click on it, I get an error message saying "Insufficient Privileges". I wonder why this would be?

Comment: @Lily swap out the word CustomFieldIDFromChildRecord with the ID of your custom field that is a lookup to the Cov__c parent object. I also beleive you need to use the Custom object Id vs the "Address__c" name in the ent parameter. What is the resulting url when you click the standard new button after you select the record type?

Comment: Oh, thanks - I made these changes... and I actually forgot to update /006/ with the correct details of my org. It's working fine now. Is there a way to pass the ID of the parent object, as the lookup field **Cov__c** is now empty on the junction object. Thanks @Jenny B

Comment: @Lily if you click on the child object then click on the parent object lookup field, up in the URL you will see the ID for that field set that parameter in the URL like the example above except replace the ID for the words representing the ID &ParentLookupFieldIDFromChildObject={!Cov__c.Id}

Comment: Thanks @Jenny B. That works now! I assume when I deploy this to production I will need to change all these ids...

Comment: Depends on of the recordType and fields existing b4 creating your sandbox or if they need to be created in production, but never hurts to dbl check!